# Laptop battery drains while asleep

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop, battery

Currently running Ubuntu 17.10 on an Acer Aspire V5-591G-56AS with Gnome 3.

Just in the past day, my laptop's battery has been draining unusually quickly while asleep. Yesterday the laptop went to sleep when fully charged (I closed the lid, and have it set to suspend on lid close), and around 12 hours later the battery was at 15% when I went to use it (previously, I've gone a day or two with maybe a 30% decrease). Today, the laptop was again fully charged. I closed the lid again, and after about two hours when I went to use it again the battery was at 50%.

I haven't changed anything with my configuration/settings/installed programs for at least 2 weeks, and the battery drain was normal up until the past two days.

I'm running both TLP and Powertop for power management. Usually when I run Powertop I see around 700-800 CPU wakes per second, now it's only at 400 but the battery is still draining incredibly quickly.

The only cause I can think of is yesterday I may have shorted a USB port with either 5V or 9V of electricity - however, the port still functions normally and is able to transfer both power and data.

Comment: "The only cause I can think of is yesterday I may have shorted a USB port" that could be the problem:if the USB tells your system there is a current running through suspend will drain power to keep the USB active."and the battery drain was normal up until the past two days." ehm you say y-day it shorted. is the "past 2 days" a guess or do you not know if it was ok the day before shorting it?If so... then the 2 are not related ;) Do you have your system set to kill wifi on suspend and to stop USB activities? I myself have those set to "no" and it then does drain the battery when not plugged in.